# new dbcontext returns all data in database?

Tags: c#, performance, entity-framework-6, linq-to-entities, dbcontext

I'm New to EF and .Net, and nothing I've read or searched-for has prepared me for what I'm seeing - any help is appreciated!

#### Question1: Why is my DbContext full of data simply upon instantiation!?

(A#1: It's not. It's just the debugger trying to help by loading data automagically.)

#### Original Question2: How do I get it to instantiate as an empty "repo/container" object for loading data via my explicit queries?

#### Better Question2: What do I pay attention to while debugging?

(A#2: Ignore the DbContext object and look at the DbSet & Query objects.)

Reason for asking:

- While Debugging, every row, from every table, is populated in Locals/ResultsView of dbcontext.
- At least the data it's returning is correct, but this would be a real performance killer :0

Think I've ruled out:

- LazyLoading is set to false
- No Linq queries have intentionally been run
- Caching issues

  - Deleting data directly in db returns empty Locals/ResultsView. (so as long as my db has no data I'm fine :p)
- Migration/db mismatch
- Type Mismatches

Haven't looked at:

- Sql profiler
- Any deep internals, IL

Have several projects in the .sln (VS2015 community) playing with CQRS pattern (EF6, MVC5, SimpleInjector)

- .Web (MVC5, DI, *deployment startup*)
- .Domain (POCO classes)
- .Data.Read (ReadDbContext, ReadDAO, EF Migrations, *designtime-startup*)

  - Using instance of LocalDB
- .Data.Write (WriteDbContext, WriteDAO)

In Data.Read project, while set to startup, the Main class has the following "Play-Code" with a breakpoint as:

```
using ( MyDbContext dbcontext = new MyDbContext() )
    {
    //BREAKPOINT:  Why is dbcontext full of data simply upon instantiation!?
    //(while Debugging, Every row, from every table, is populated in Locals/ResultsView of dbcontext)
    //No explicit Linq queries have been run
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why is my DbContext full of data simply upon instantiation!?

`DbContext` does not load the data. Your debugger does. The debugger allows you to view the data, and when you view it the `DbContext` will query the database. But it won't do it otherwise. This can easily be tested with SQL Server Profiler. Run it up and you will see that your `DbContext` doesn't query your database until you use your debugger to view it.

> How do I get it to instantiate as an empty "repo/container" object for
>   loading data via my explicit queries?

The most simple way would be to just get the table.

Say that your `DbContext` looks like this:

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Customer> Customers {get; set;}
}
```

Then you can get your container like so:

```
using(var context = new MyDbContext())
{
    // Get the table. This can serve as your repository.
    DbSet<Customer> table = context.Customers;

    // If you're using generics you can do like this as well.
    DbSet<Customer> otherTable = context.Set<Customer>();

    // Specify your explicit query.
    IQueryable<Customer> query = table.Where(x => x.Name == 'Jenny');

    // Note that EF still haven't executed a query.
    // By calling methods like ToList() or FirstOrDefault() it will run the query.
    IList<Customer> result = query.ToList();
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much!  Question 2 was predicated on "believing my lying eyes", but thanks for the added detail!  
I'll take my answer #2 from your examples as: "just look at 'table', 'otherTable', 'query', 'result' while debugging, and ignore 'context' "